# Prove $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(B\cap C)$.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If $A, B, C$ are events, and $P(A\vert B)=1$, prove $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(B\cap C)$.

I have tried to prove it.

$P(A\vert B)=1\iff \dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=1\iff P(A\cap B)=P(B)$.

Is it right, if 
$$P(A\cap B)=P(B)$$
then
$$A\cap B=B,$$
so
$$A\cap B\cap C=B\cap C,$$
and we have
$$P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(B\cap C)?$$

Comment: You cannot conclude that $\textsf{P}(A\cap B) = \textsf{P}(B)$ implies $A\cap B = B$.

Comment: Have you considered using the multiplication rule?

Comment: As Azif00 said, you cannot say $A\cap B= B$  from $P(A\cap B)=P(B)$ because you don't have that $B-A$ is an empty set. In fact, $B-A$ could be an infinite set. By the way, by $P$ I mean Lebesgue (probability) measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from where you got stuck: $P(A\cap B)=P(B)$
\begin{align}
P(B)=P(B\setminus A)+P(A\cap B)&\implies P(B\setminus A)=0\\
&\implies 0\leq P((B\setminus A)\cap C)\leq P(B\setminus A)=0\\
&\implies P((B\setminus A)\cap C)=0\\
 &\implies P(B\cap C)=P(A\cap B\cap C) +P((B\setminus A)\cap C)\\
&\implies P(B\cap C)= P(A\cap B\cap C).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_A, X_B$, and $X_C$ be the indicator variables corresponding to the events $A, B,$ and $C$. From the given relation, we have
$\mathbb{E}(X_B(1-X_A))=0$.
However, due to the non-negativity of the term within expectation, we have almost surely, $X_B(1-X_A)=0$.
The result now follows by multiplying both sides by $X_C$ and taking expectation.